# java server socket in cloud server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, cloud

So I have two java classes for socket server and client as follows:

**For the server:**

```
System.out.println("Server started:");
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1935, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
    Socket connection = new Socket();
    while(active){
        connection = server.accept();
        printTimeStamp();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        while(in.available() == 0){
            //waiting till message is complete
        }
        MessageDecode(in);
    }
```

MessageDecode is just an internal method that reads the input streams and stores it somewhere

**for the client**

```
Socket connectionSocket = new Socket();
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("THE_CLOUD_SERVER_IP");
        SocketAddress sAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, 1935);
        connectionSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
        connectionSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        connectionSocket.connect(sAddress, 2000);
        OutputStream os = connectionSocket.getOutputStream();
        os.write("HELLO SERVER".getBytes());
        os.close();
        System.out.println("sent");
```

when I run both on a localhost it works like a charm, but when I run the class into the cloud server, I get timout exception `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`

even when the por is listening, I know its listening because when I run the app, and do a netstat -anp I get:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1935              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      PID/java
```

can someone give me a clue on how to solve this?
your help is must appreciated.
Thanks (._.')

Comment: `but when I the server class to the server` - I think you accidentally a word there.

Comment: yeah, I meant when I run the class in the cloud server... sorry about that.

Comment: Can you start the server on the cloud and telnet to its port? If not you may have a firewall on the way. Just because ``netstat`` says that your listening in a certain port, doesn't mean it is reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, cloud providers do not allow to open low level sockets (even WebSocket are rarely allowed). They usually use a proxy in front of the Java application server. Cloud providers are often used for HTTP application.

If you really want to use sockets, leave your current cloud provider and open an account on Amazon EC2.